# Using buttons within a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-sdk-2.3

I am trying to use a ViewPager where users can interact within each pane. For this ViewPager, I am creating a tutorial where I show users to swipe horizontally to switch pane. When the user reaches the last pane, a button is displayed to the user where they will be navigated to the dashboard. I have read a few articles trying to understand how a button works within a ViewPager, but could not really make much sense.

What the code should do is when a button within a pane within a ViewPager is clicked, the dashboard activity is started.

Here is the full code of the pagerAdapter:

```
class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

 public int getCount() {

    return 5;
 }

public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

    View v = new View(collection.getContext());

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    int resId = 0;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        resId = R.layout.tutorial_step1;
    break;

    case 1:
        resId = R.layout.tutorial_step2;

    break;

    case 2:
        resId = R.layout.tutorial_step3;
    break;

    case 3:
        resId = R.layout.tutorial_step4;

    break;

    case 4:
        resId = R.layout.tutorial_complete;
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tutorial_complete, null, false);
        LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.llComplete);
        Button button=(Button)l.findViewById(R.id.bTutorialComplete);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Create an intent that starts a different activity
            }
        });
        break;
    }
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(v, 0);

    return v;

}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);

}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);

}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
 }
}
```

From what I have seen in articles, the code I should be working with is:

```
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

    View v = new View(collection.getContext());

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    int resId = 0;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        resId = R.layout.tutorial_step1;
    break;

    case 1:
        resId = R.layout.tutorial_step2;

    break;

    case 2:
        resId = R.layout.tutorial_step3;
    break;

    case 3:
        resId = R.layout.tutorial_step4;

    break;

    case 4:
        resId = R.layout.tutorial_complete;
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tutorial_complete, null, false);
        LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.llComplete);
        Button button=(Button)l.findViewById(R.id.bTutorialComplete);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Create an intent that starts a different activity
            }
        });
        break;
    }
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(v, 0);

    return v;

}
```

It is only `case 4:` within the `switch` statement that I am working with as this has a button whereas the other layouts only contain images and text which requires no interaction.

I have been working on this for countless hours now and still couldn't figure out a way to resolve this. I would be very grateful if you can help me with this.

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question is.  Are you trying to figure out how to make the layout for the view with the button?  Or are you trying to figure out how to create an intent to start an activity?  Or something else?  The code looks alright so far.  If you can supply your layouts and any LogCat which shows an error, that would be helpful as well in answering your question.

Comment: I have provided the layouts in the switch statement, but one of the layouts has a button. I want that button to create an intent to start an activity. I tried creating an intent and starting an activity within the switch statement but the compiler doesn't accept it, it doesn't recognise this intent arguments and the startActivity method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    final Context context = collection.getContext();
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, Dashboard.class));
        }
    });
    break;
```

P.s. you cannot make `collection` `final` since the method `instantiateItem` is an `@Override`

Hint: if you want to make pages that are different you can put your code in `switch(position)`:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)
View v = null;
switch (position) {
    case 0:
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.somelayout);
        Button btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.somebutton);
        btn.setText("btn");
    break;

    case 1:
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.someotherlayout);
        TextView tv = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.sometextview);
        tv.setText("btn");
    break;
}

((ViewPager) collection).addView(v, 0);
return v;
```

Comment: I'll give this a go as well as the answer below, thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to create an intent and then start an activity with it.  You can use the context from "collection" which you are already accessing.  Here's some code which should get you going again:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Context context = collection.getContext();
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DashboardActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Note that you'll probably have to make collection become final.

Comment: Tried it out, had a problem with it, but managed to get an understanding and try it out myself, thank you for your help!