# Change content of a page in 4 page in ViewPager

Tags: android, calendar, android-viewpager

At the moment,I have a viewpager and added 4 page to it.
I also have 4 button correspond with 4 page..
When click button1,load only content of page1
When click button2,load only content of page2
...vv
In android,have function to set content for only a page in pages of viewpager??

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible duplicate of [Using buttons within a ViewPager.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9695222/2219600)

This answer is from the same question:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)
 View v = null;
switch (position) {
case 0:
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.somelayout);
    Button btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.somebutton);
    btn.setText("btn");
break;

case 1:
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.someotherlayout);
    TextView tv = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.sometextview);
    tv.setText("btn");
break;
```

}

```
((ViewPager) collection).addView(v, 0);
return v;
```